# Why doesn't `eval` work inside my loop?

Tags: bash

Using eval on a string that contains a command that defines a function works without problem:

```
$ eval "p4() { echo 4; }"
$ p4
4
```

However, when I do it like this it no longer works:

```
$ echo 'p3() { echo 3; }' | while read line ; do eval "$line"; done
$ p3
-bash: p3: command not found
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I'm not sure you should be playing around with `eval` if you don't understand subshells yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is happening due to a sub-shell being spawned due to your pipeline after `echo`. That is declaring function `p3` in sub-shell, not accessible from current (parent) shell.

You can avoid it by using here-string instead of pipeline:

```
while read line ; do eval "$line"; done <<< 'p3() { echo 3; }'

p3
3
```

Answer (score 4):

What [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36923385/171318) is saying is correct and you should always keep that in mind. Let me just suggest an alternative: you may use process substitution and `source`:

```
source <(echo 'p3() { echo 3; }')
p3
```

The question is, why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 3):

From `man bash`:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

Since variables aren't transferred to the subshell, `p3` isn't accessible there.

As an aside: `zsh` executes the second example exactly the way you expected, that is, it outputs `3`.